# Can't get Google fit data in react app: error 400, 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-fit

I'm trying to fetch daily data from google fit api, but
I don't understand what's wrong in my request. I'm trying to get daily step count but I still recive error 401. Here is all the code implemented and i'm just trying to log the response.

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ haslogin: false, accessToken: "" });

  function login(response) {
    if (response.wc.access_token) {
      setUser({
        ...response.profileObj,
        haslogin: true,
        accessToken: response.wc.access_token,
      });
    }
  }

  function logout(response) {
    setUser({ haslogin: false, accessToken: "" });
  }

  function handleLoginFailure(response) {
    alert("Failed to log in");
  }
  function handleLogoutFailure(response) {
    alert("Failed to log out");
  }
const handleData = () => {
    Axios.post(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate",
      {
        aggregateBy: [
          {
            dataTypeName: "com.google.step_count.delta",
            dataSourceId:
              "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",
          },
        ],
        bucketByTime: { durationMillis: 86400000 },
        startTimeMillis: 1438705622000,
        endTimeMillis: 1439310422000,
      },
      {
        params: {
          key: API_KEY,
        },
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.accessToken}`,
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("res", response);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: 401 means unauthorised - perhaps you're not authorised to access the data you're requesting

Comment: @Bravo the result in that case would be 403 forbidden. The fact the OP is getting a 401 indicates that the access token being passed is invalid.

Comment: True, @AndyTurner that always trips me up

Comment: You can also verify backend responses and to preview an authentication flow from the Google Fit using OAuth Playground. This should return an error if something isn’t right with the OAuth consent screen so you could fix them right away https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started#try_the_rest_api_in_the_oauth_playground